# Memory Management in ARC

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I could not understand how the objects are released in ARC, there is still a confusion going on in this for me.

Suppose i create a view controller or any other using alloc in a method

```
    -(void) displayView
    {
       RegViewController *sampleView = [[RegViewController alloc] init];
       [sampleView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
       [sampleView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
       [self presentModalViewController:sampleView animated:YES];
    }
```

Does it release the object created when the method block completes or we should explicitly release by giving nil to reference?

Comment: when using ARC the compiler will include the necessaries calls to the `release` method when an object gets out of scope (is no longer required), in a beginning there is no difference between release of an ARC and a not ARC application.

Comment: Yes scope is the only concern with ARC.

Answer (score 1):

in this case **sampleView** will be released when the modal view is dismissed. one does not need to do anything else in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The view controller is automatically released at the end of the block. However this does **not** mean that it is deallocated - it is still retained by the `presentModalViewController:animated:` method and will be released (and deallocated) when it is dismissed.

Comment: Well spotted, but on dismiss it should go away.

Comment: If we dismiss the view controller , then would it get deallocated?

Comment: Remember all strong references to an object must be nullified for ARC to release it. In this case the dismiss method should nullify some variable in order to release it.

Answer (score 0):

ARC stands for Automatic Reference Counting.
It takes over the user's responsibility for maintaining object reference counting.
That's why you can't call `[obj retain]` or `[obj release]` anymore.
It releases it for you as soon as the reference counter hits 0.
Just remember that it is not a garbage collector. There are cases where this mechanism can cause memory leaks if you're not careful. But in general it works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Does it release the object created when the method block completes or we should explicitly release by giving nil to reference?
```

Answer is **NO**.

In the above case `sampleView` retain count is not reaching 0, as you passed this as an argument to `self` class. Once all the strong reference will be cleared its retain count will come down to 0, only after that it will get release.

You can simply imagine your code as `RegViewController *sampleView = [[[RegViewController alloc] init] autorelease];`